# Merge firebase events on bigquery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to bring together the events recorded on firebase for android and ios, but when I try to perform an union on the tables, I get:

> Error: Duplicate column names in the result are not supported. Found duplicate(s): user_dim, event_dim

My query (standardSQL):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
 `com_myapp_ANDROID.app_events_*`,
 `com_myapp_IOS.app_events_*`
```

I can select the fields independently and create aliases, but then I won't have a real merge why I would like to import into google data studio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM `com_myapp_ANDROID.app_events_*`
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `com_myapp_IOS.app_events_*`
LIMIT 11
```

comma as a UNION works only in BigQuery Legacy SQL - comma is treated as CROSS JOIN in BigQuery Standard SQL
In BigQuery Standard SQL you must use UNION explicitly

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! It worked like a charm, I don't know why I thought it was actually the other way around.

Comment: Yes, I had to wait a bit after you edit it, you were too quick spotting my mistake!

Comment: The query works fine on bigquery, but if I try it to use it as a data source on data studio, I get:

Error Details

There`s a query error.

3.3 - 5.8: Unrecognized token SetOperation

Comment: SO assumes one question per post. Followup new questions in comments is really hard to answer and not welcomed here. I recommend you to post new question with specifics to your new issue and we will be happy to help. hope this makes sense to you